# Forbidden error from android to magento

Tags: access

I have a file which is stored in magento root.If I access this file from browser like : localhost/test_magento/new.php,it works fine.

But when I tried to access this file from android mobile it always respond me with "403 Forbidden : You don't have permission to access /test_magento/new.php on this server".

Where I am going wrong ?

Comment: this is problem my site and i have use this code and resloved the problem.

Comment: probably you have some ACL in your htaccess file, that blocks user agent string or device type or ip address??

Comment: Cam you please elaborate this ? How to overcome or find this ?

Comment: As @ADM already mentioned: Check your .htaccess file for any `Deny from...` section.

Comment: I have set all to "Allow from all" But no change in situation.

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions and user, this error usually occurs when you do not have access. 
Try PHP [get_current_user()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php) in your script to access the user you are accessing the script with.

Then if you have command line access (ssh) proceed to your script and perform:

```
ls -alh
```

This will list the file, its owner and its permissions. The owner or group of your script may not be accessible from the user on your android device. It may not be readable to others, something like: **rwxrwx---** (the last 3 dashes represent access to other users other than the group and owner).

Perform a:

```
chmod a+r your-script.php
```

To change its permissions and give that a try. Let me know if you have a problems.